# Pegging a private chain to Ethereum public blockchain

Tags: sidechain, tutorials

Are there any good tutorials or resources for sidechain development or are these just specialized private chain pegged to the Ethereum network?

Answer (score 2):

There are more resources coming on line
If your looking  for a private block-chain, for example your own sidechain on ETH with and a choice of consensus, look at Ark  with its modular plugin system. Ark uses what it calls "smart bridges" to connect to a  public ETH,to provide services or even act as interfaces for other third-party services. Its most developed sdk is javascript.

see [ark](https://docs.ark.io/guidebook/core/development.html#introduction)
for a detailed  tech outline to the stack, they have a cookbook with code snippets there as well

Answer (score 1):

There are no tutorials, because the state of the art is still in Research & Development and nobody has deployed a true sidechain yet.

As far as I know, at the moment there is no decentralized way to set up sidechains. For example, one of the most popular projects Rootstock (RSK) is using a "federation" e.g. centralized wallet do to the pegging.

https://faq.rsk.co/en/main/ (see: Federation)

Work-in-progress projects include

- [Cosmos](https://cosmos.network/)
- [Polkadot](https://polkadot.network/)
- Plasma - could not really find a better link to report the state of the progress than this one https://blog.omisego.network/construction-of-a-plasma-chain-0x1-614f6ebd1612

Answer (score 0):

[Rootstock](https://www.rsk.co/) side-chain allows users to use smart contracts with bitcoin. you convert your "btc" to "rbtc" to interact with the smart contracts.

From [here](https://academy.bit2me.com/en/que-es-rootstock-rsk/)

> The RSK platform is a language based protocol Solidity it works like a
> side chain running in parallel to the Bitcoin blockchain. This
> protocol is based on a bidirectional communication that operates as a
> bridge to connect both chains. In this way, it allows the Bitcoin
> network to assist RSK in its execution. That is why the native
> currency or token of the RSK platform is the RSK smart bitcoin (RBTC),
> which has a 1: 1 ratio with the original currency of the Bitcoin
> network, bitcoin (BTC).
>
> Thanks to the functionality of this platform, today it is possible to
> enjoy decentralized applications (DApps) and complex smart contracts
> within the Bitcoin network, much like they occur within Bitcoin
> networks. Ethereum, EOS and others. But with all the security and
> robustness that the Bitcoin blockchain enjoys thanks to its great
> computing power.

- `Polygon` is a side chain for ethereum.

Answer (score -7):

Wwhy would one need an ethereum sidechain if ethereum is turing complete? That just makes little sense. It's not a scalability conversation, that's a stupid way of scaling. It's the equivalent of fixing something with duct tape.

For a blockchain like bitcoin it makes somewhat sense because it can extend functionality of the protocol but even then there's issues. Atomic swap is nothing but a fancy word for an automated escrow and there's big potential hazards like centralization (see LN hubs), fraudulent swaps, ... . Not to mention it's only possible through local daemon.

Comment: I am downvoting this because this is a rant, not an answer to the question.

Comment: For ranting needs, please engage the likeminded people in Reddit, but leave it out from the professional conversation.

Comment: Thanks @MikkoOhtamaa ! It's important to keep vitreole off this site

Comment: I'm sorry snowflakes, but these are facts.

Comment: Even if these are the facts and correct, this is not an answer to the question but starts with another question.